# Which one of the following versions of Bayes' theorem is correct?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, bayes-theorem

I've seen two versions of Bayes' theorem:

I've seen this very long version from a frequentist probability class:
$$
P(B|A)=\frac{P(A|B)P(B)}{P(A|B)P(B) + P(A|B^c)P(B^c)}
$$
where $B^c$ is the event that $B$ did not happen. I've seen the following on the internet:
$$
P(B|A)=\frac{P(A|B)P(B)}{P(A)}.
$$

Are these equivalent? Is one wrong? Is one a bayesian probability version and the other a frequentist probability version?

Comment: They're equivalent, based on the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability).

Comment: They are the same. In fact, even simpler is  P(B|A) = P(A∩B)/P(A)

Comment: It's not Baye's theorem, it's Bayes' theorem. It's the theorem of a person called Bayes, not Baye.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two versions are equivalent. By the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability), $P(A) = P(A,B) + P(A,B^c) = P(A|B)P(B) + P(A|B^c)P(B^c)$.

The second version is more compact (and arguably gives a better intuition as to what the theorem means), but when you go to evaluate $P(A)$ you often have to decompose it as in the first version, so its application is more direct.

Answer (score 2):

Both formulations are identical. Note that the denominator in both cases is the same based on the law of total probability, which in this case states

For two events $A$ and $B$, it states
$$P(A)=P(A\cap B)+P(A\cap B^c)$$
but using $P(A\cap B)=P(A|B)P(B)$, it is written
$$
P(A)=P(A|B)P(B)+P(A|B)^cP(B^c).
$$